# Show Div in <td> tag and span over full table space

Tags: html, angular

I have a table in which the last column has a clickable arrow to display a nested table underneath.

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dData of dDatas;>
            <td>{{dData.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{dData.Desc}}</td>
            <td>
                <div (click)="onClick()"><span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': dcData.opendPanel , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !dcData.opendPanel }"></span></div>
                <div [hidden]="!dData.opendPanel">
                    //another table
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is the inner table comes in the last `<td>` and the formatting isn't correct. I want to make the inner table to appear in a new row and span over the width of the outer table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should utilise `<ng-container>`. This allows you you include multiple `<tr>` tags in each iteration of your for loop, giving your inner table a whole row and the ability to span the width of the table.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dData of dDatas>
    <tr >
        <td>{{dData.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{dData.Desc}}</td>
        <td> 
            <div (click)="onClick()">
                <span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': dcData.opendPanel , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !dcData.opendPanel }"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
             <div [hidden]="!dData.opendPanel">
                 //another table
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
</ng-container>
```

> `<ng-container>` is a logical container that can be used to group nodes but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node.